# "No such file or directory" from CGI program, but executes from the shell

Tags: perl, cgi, symlink

I have a Perl CGI script which runs another Perl program using `system`.

I added an `-x` test before the call to `system` and it evaluates as *true* when run from the shell but *false* when executed by the CGI server. The file is a symbolic link.

When I use the absolute file path, then it also evaluates as *true* on the web, but when executing the conditional code, I receive a `No such file or directory` error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';

our ($CMD) = '/relative/path/file';

if ( -x $CMD ) {
  my $output;
  $output = system($CMD);
  print $output;
}
```

The result of `ls -l /relative/path/file` is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root something 19398 Sep 23 00:00 /relative/path/file
```

In summary

- The code works when executed on the shell, but not on the web
- If I use the relative path, `-x` the test evaluates as false
- If I use the full path, `-x` evaluates as true, but the `system()` call throws a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: Is your relative path in `/tmp` and is this RHEL/Centos 7+? Because that's another gotcha. PrivateTmp

Comment: The return value from `system` is a status value, not the output of the command.

Comment: Does the path contain spaces? Try using `system(qq{"$CMD"})`. I think you need to tell us what the real value of `$CMD` is. I understand about privacy considerations, but if you change the code from the original then we are left casting around in the dark.

Comment: It is unclear how you're specifying the file path. Your dummy path is `/relative/path/file`, but a path starting with `/` is an _absolute_ path. Relative paths don't start with `/`. This is a relevant distinction here because, if you actually are using a relative path, then the issue is likely to be that CGI will run the code from a different working directory than the directory you're in when you run it from the shell.

Comment: @DaveSherohman I _think_ the OP means "relative path=/path/to/symlink" and "absolute path=/path/to/symlink/resolved" (both being absolute paths in the usual sense). But that's only a guess.

Comment: @Sobrique, the path is not in `/tmp`

@Borodin, regardless of the result from `system()` the problem is it doesn't execute what's supposed to

@DaveSherohman, @PerlDuck is correct and I may have not been very clear about what I mean by a "relative path" what I mean by that is the symlink path and what I mean by "absolute path" is the real path the symlink points to, but both are absolute unix paths

Comment: Did you try `su -s /bin/sh www-data -c "cat /symlink/path/to/file"` and `su -s /bin/sh www-data -c "cat /resolved/symlink/path/to/file"`?

Comment: If that is the output of `ls -l` then `/relative/path/file` isn't a symlink.

Comment: @Borodin, when I do `cd /relative/path` followed by `pwd` I get the output `/some/other/path`

Comment: @JoaoPestana: I don't think that's relevant except to demonstrate that `/relative/path` is a link to a directory, so *"The file is a symbolic link"* is untrue. If `ls -l /relative/path/file` is showing that output then `/relative/path/file` isn't a symbolic link. And please stop calling it *relative*; that means something else altogether.

Comment: @JoaoPestana: What does `ls -l /relative/path` show?

Comment: This was already asked, but it wasn't answered: Is `/relative/path/file` an absolute path (starts with `/`) or a relative path (doesn't start with `/`)?

Comment: @ikegami, it's an absolute path
@Borodin, the command `ls -l /relative/path` returns a list of files including `file`

Comment: That's good. Many people assume the CWD is the directory in which the script is located when it's often not. Did you check the permissions of /relative, /relative/path, /some, /some/other and /some/other/path yet?

Comment: @ikegami, Yes, that was one of the first things I checked. All permissions are good.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're not calling Perl when trying to run your script?

```
$output = system("perl $CMD");
```

Comment: I tried several variations of that, including explicitly calling perl to run the command as you suggested to the same result.

Comment: Try running your command with backtits like this:  ``my $output = `perl $CMD`; ``
Then print and analyze the result, maybe that´ll help
EDIT: just trying to get those backtits to show properly

Answer (score 0):

Just a possibility... Is the file not found coming out of some code running in the /relative/path/file? Possibly it accesses some relative paths in its code?

Comment: I believe I've found the problem to be something like that. The script I'm trying to run has a shebang for a different perl version. This is a third party script and I believe that particular version is not available in the server that runs the CGI script I wrote.